# Unable to print number of characters using getchar, in Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, getchar

I am new to C, and to Ubuntu. I wrote a very simple program to count the number of characters using `while` and `getchar()`. The program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()  {

    int i;
    int c= 0;

    while ( ( i = getchar() ) != EOF ){
        c++ ;
    }
    printf( "%d characters\n" , c) ;

    return 0;
}
```

I saved it and compiled it using `gcc c1.c -o c1`. No errors reported. I executed the program using `./c1` . I give the input as *daniweb* then I press enter, but the count is displayed. What went wrong? Is it infinite loop? How does `getchar()` determine `EOF` when input is given from keyboard?

Comment: The count *is* displayed or the count *is not* displayed ? Try typing Control-D when you're done entering text.

Answer (score 1):

On the terminal you can send EOF to an application by pressing Ctrl+D. You can also do something like this:

```
echo "blablub" | ./yourprogram
```

To count how many characters are in blablub. In this case EOF is sent automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing enter sends a new line character to your program, not EOF. As others have mention already, use Ctrl+D to send EOF. If you want to stop reading characters on newline, change your while loop to this:

```
while ( ( i = getchar() ) != '\n' ){
c++ ;
}
```